# Migrating DomainName from Godaddy to AWS route53 using AWS SDK or api

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-route53, awss3transfermanager

Suppose I have domain "www.example.com" on godaddy. I have hosted zone as well as resource record set on Godaddy also.

Now I want to bind my domain with AWS route 53. so let me know whether we can do that or not,,

and if yes then how we can manage it using AWS SDK. 
Are we required to have hosted zone and resource record set on AWS Route 53 also????

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you wish to host your DNS in AWS but maintain your registration in GoDaddy.

You can create a Public Hosted Zone in Route53 for your domain. You will then need to update your name servers to be the ones that AWS will provide you when you create your hosted zone at your Domain Registrar (in this case your Domain Registrar is GoDaddy).

Once this is done you will be able to manage your DNS in Route53. Keep in mind that it can take some time for these nameserver changes to take effect around the world and it is not unusual to see this propagation happen in a non intuitive order.

Regarding to the Route53 SDK, I am not certain which platform you wish to use the SDK so I will link a few common ones below for you along with some documentation for Route53 and the GoDaddy FAQ for updating your Name Servers.

If however you wish to transfer your domain's registration from GoDaddy to AWS I have also included this link for you at the very end.

Cheers,

Xavier.

Updating your Name Servers at GoDaddy
https://au.godaddy.com/help/set-custom-nameservers-for-domains-registered-with-godaddy-12317

Route53 Documentation
https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/route53/

AWS Tools for PowerShell Cmdlets
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/Index.html

AWS CLI (Linux)
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/

AWS .Net SDK
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/route53-apis-intro.html

AWS Javascript SDK
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Route53.html

Transferring a Domains Registration to AWS
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-transfer-to-route-53.html